# In Angular 2 how can I perform form validation on a child component?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which has a child component.

The child component is a user details page where they input the name etc.

At the moment, I have wired it up so that the submit button on the form has a `(click)` which uses an eventemitter to inform the parent component they have submitted the form. The model is using a 2 way binding so the parent component can pick up the changes.

Since I am not using form submit, model validation doesn't trigger on clicking the button.

Is there a better way that involves using a submit to get the data to the parent component and thus triggers form validation, or is there a way to manually activate the form validation and only proceed to triggering the event if it is valid?

User Details Component:

```
<h2>User Details</h2>
<label>Name</label>   {{userDetailsModel.Name}}<br>
<button (click)="formSubmitted();">Submit</button>
```

Form submitted method:

```
@Output() 
notification: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

formSubmitted() {
    this.notification.emit("submit_click");
}
```

Parent component:

```
<h2>Parent Component</h2>
<app-user-details [user]="user" 
    (notification)="notificationReceived($event)">
</app-user-details>
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Posted the code

Comment: form validation is there regardless if you submit or not